# Synonym of word "last" for some special case

Tags: synonyms, abbreviations

There are two special abbreviations showing the significance (or 'weight') of a bit in a set (or nibble): **lsb** *(least significant bit)*, **msb** *(most significant bit)*. Both "lsb" and "msb" are not general English words therefore that abbreviations could be unambiguously distinguished among other words within sentences.

Similarly, i search for a pair of terms for first and last [bit transmitted] on wire, i.e. defining the transmission order of a bit in a set. And if with first-on-wire - abbreviated as **fow** - i see no trouble because "fow" is not a common English word (as Google Translate assures me), abbreviating of last-on-wire results in the well-known word "low" which could rise disambiguations.

Google Translate gives a rare (as I assume) synonym for the word "last"—the word "dernier" (adj.) that results in dernier-on-wire and **dow**, which is not a common English word today. Then **fow:dow** seems as a good pair, based on this. But...

1) Is it correct? (I am not native speaker; it's difficult for to me to understand these kinds of things by myself.)

2) Are there other synonyms for "last" and "first" more widely known/used that would be more comfortable/relevant in this case (whose abbreviations also must/should not intersect with general/common English words)?

Beforehand thanks.

Comment: Ultimate.  And the one before that is penultimate.

Comment: Jinx! @HotLicks lol!

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with "last"?

Comment: How about FoW and LoW? Might be enough to caution reader it's not a word...

Comment: @anemone FoW/LoW are case-sensitive, case-insensitive are preferable, e.g. xmitdata[fow:dow] = 1010101 :-)

Comment: @asndre Well, I don't know about your context. But in the context you've quoted, I wouldn't worry about 'low' being a word.

Answer (score 2):

***"Ultimate"*** fits both your criteria as a replacement for "last" and won't be confused with a common English word..."UOW"

Per the Google Dictionary, [ultimate](https://www.google.com/#q=ultimate+definition), in this sense, is defined as:

> adjective: ultimate
>
> 1. being or happening at the end of a process; final.
>
> Example: "their ultimate aim was to force his resignation"

I perused the synonyms but sadly, "concluding" and "terminal" would spell "COW" or "TOW", both common English words

Comment: fow is for final-on-wire... what is for first-on-wire in that case?

Comment: oops!  my bad!  Removing "Final" from my answer since I can't use another word to replace "first" ("beginning" doesn't work either..."BOW".)  Thanks @asndre!

Comment: And what about "dernier"? Is it correct synonym for adj. "last" for your opinion?

Comment: @asndre - "dernier" is not a common English word.  In fact, it only appears to be used as a part of several borrowed French idioms.

Answer (score 1):

Best and most common:

## Former & Latter

*You may abbreviate "former" as "fmr." and "latter" as "ltr.".*

That is one of the best and most common set of synonyms used in place of "first" and "last". Though they are not precisely interchangeable, they work in many situations.

Consider this [article](http://editingandwritingservices.com/former-latter/).

---

Alternatively, if you need to be irregular and create something special or more concise, consider FST & LST:

1. FST is proper

"FST" is a proper abbreviation for "first", so "LST" naturally fits for readers, even with no prior knowledge, merely by the juxtaposition.

2. Use uppercase, not lowercase (in this situation)

Using lowercase letters would be a bad idea because in many serif and Roman fonts the "l" (L) looks like a "1" (one) so "lst" (LST) looks like "1st" (1 ST).

3. Don't punctuate (in this situation)

Don't use a period because then "last" has the same number of characters as "lst."; using capital letters would clear this up.

Comment: Are "former" and "latter" applicable for time-related (ordered in time) events? (The article you given show only "time-less" ("time-independent") examples.) Is it suitable to use these words in my scope, i.e. (at least in the sense of) "former-on-wire", "latter-on-wire"?

Comment: Generally, yes, they can work with time. Consider "former president" and "Latter Day Saints".

Comment: Certainly! Make sure you "Check" the correct answer. ;-)